# Select rows from pandas data frame where specified columns are not all NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, na

I have a Pandas DataFrame object `data` with columns `'a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z'`

I want to select all rows which satisfy the following condition:  data in columns `'b'`, `'c'`, `'g'` is not NaN simultaneously. I tried:

```
new_data = data[not all(np.isnan(value) for value in data[['b', 'c', 'g']])]
```

but it didn't work - throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>`
  File "<input>", line 1, in <genexpr>
 TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: @toti08 added the error in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to select all rows, which qualify the following condition: data in columns 'b', 'c', 'g' is not NaN simultaneously.*

Then you can use `dropna`:

```
new_data = data.dropna(how='all', subset=['b', 'c', 'g'])
```

using [parameters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
how : {'any', 'all'}
    * any : if any NA values are present, drop that label
    * all : if all values are NA, drop that label
subset : array-like
    Labels along other axis to consider, e.g. if you are dropping rows
    these would be a list of columns to include
```