# Drop dataframe columns where all rows AND header is na

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that holds a number of NoneType values and I would like to drop all columns where all the row values AND the header is None. I am struggling to find a way to do this. In the **MWE** below I have managed to either drop all columns where all the rows are None OR drop all columns where the header is None.

```
from __future__ import annotations

import pandas as pd

d = [[1, 2, None, None, None], [4, 5, None, None, 7]]
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', None, None]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=cols)

print("Original: \n", df)
#Original: 
#    a  b     c   NaN  NaN
#0  1  2  None  None  NaN
#1  4  5  None  None  7.0

print("\nDropped how = all: \n", df.dropna(axis=1, how="all"))    # Drops column 'c'
#Dropped how = all: 
#    a  b  NaN
#0  1  2  NaN
#1  4  5  7.0

print("\nDropped None columns: \n", df[df.columns.dropna()])
#Dropped None columns: 
#    a  b     c
#0  1  2  None
#1  4  5  None
```

How can I drop only the columns I want to drop and get this?

```
#Wanted: 
#    a  b     c  NaN
#0  1  2  None   NaN
#1  4  5  None   7.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: drop columns with all NaN's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147100/pandas-drop-columns-with-all-nans)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use 2 conditions with an `&` and invert and use `.loc[]`:

```
df.loc[:,~(df.columns.isna() & df.isna().all())]
```

---

```
   a  b     c  NaN
0  1  2  None  NaN
1  4  5  None  7.0
```

Comment: DeMorgan's version `df.loc[:, df.notna().any() | df.columns.notna()]`

Comment: @piRSquared Nice 1, more efficient I believe . Thank you Sir :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way using `notna` and `any` and performing boolean indexing on the dataframe based on the conditions:

```
df.loc[:, (df.notna() | df.columns.notna()).any(0)]

   a  b     c  NaN
0  1  2  None  NaN
1  4  5  None  7.0
```

Answer (score 4):

IIUC

```
df.loc[:,df.T.reset_index().notna().any(1).values]
   a  b     c  NaN
0  1  2  None  NaN
1  4  5  None  7.0
```

Comment: This exactly the first thing I thought of.  Well close `df.loc[:, [*df.T.reset_index().notna().any(1)]]`