# What is the best approach to remove in pandas all columns with all values equals to False?

Tags: pandas

I've seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147100/pandas-drop-columns-with-all-nans) how to drop columns with all `nan`, but I'm looking for a way to remove all columns with all `False` values.

Using the info in that question, I'm thinking of replacing False with nan, dropping them, and then replacing `nan` back with `False`, but I don't know if that is the best approach.

A working piece of code with my approach would be as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[True, True, False], 'B': [False, True, False], 'C':[False, False, False], 'D': [True, True, True]})

df.replace(to_replace=False, value=np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
df.fillna(False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: `df.loc[:, df.any()]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
df.loc[:,~df.eq(False).all()]
```

**Output:**

```
    A       B       D
0   True    False   True
1   True    True    True
2   False   False   True
```

Comment: Thanks, that is much better